# NoMethodError: undefined method `duration' for nil:NilClass

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, view

I am writing test class to execute my method class ( in method class there is a sql statement which is going to execute)
but `NoMethodError: undefined method`duration' for nil:NilClass` is given.

```
class AverageTimeForFirstReferralTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    user2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    user2.referrer_id = user1.id
    user2.created_at = 1.month.from_now
  end

  def test_creating_view_for_avg_time_for_first_ref
    AverageTimeForFirstReferral.update_view_command();
    assert_equal(1.month * 1.hour, AverageTimeForFirstReferral.first.duration)
  end
end
```

method class is below :

```
class AverageTimeForFirstReferral < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def update_view_command
      # executing the sql statement
      self.connection.execute %Q( CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW average_time_for_first_referrals AS
                                  SELECT u.id, u.created_at user_created_at, u.referrer_id, r.`created_at` referrer_created_at, TIMEDIFF('r.created_at','u.created_at') as Time_Diff
                                  from users u inner join users r
                                  on u.`referrer_id`= r.`id`
                                  WHERE TIMEDIFF(r.created_at,u.created_at)  > 0;)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like there are now rows in your table `AverageTimeForFirstReferral` you need to create one using factory girl.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement doesn't create any records at `AverageTimeForFirstReferral` model's table .. That's why.

Comment: Thanks. I created my own TIMEDIFF function like as:
create  function TIMEDIFF (start_date DateTime, end_date DateTime) RETURNS decimal(10,2)
RETURN Datediff(start_date, end_date) * 24.0 + (extract(hour from end_date) - extract(hour from start_date)) + (extract(minute from end_date) - extract(minute from start_date)) / 60

and it is working now